# communicate between a python gui and already existing app which was developed in Tcl/Tk

Tags: python

i have a gui which have several functionalities in it.Now i want the gui to talk to already existing Medina pre processor which is developed in Tcl/Tk. In the gui when i press the button process it should talk to the medina through pipe.
The medina pre-processor can talk to python script through pipes. but i don't know how to do it. to understand what is medina one can see this documentation [here](https://servicenet.t-systems.de/t-systems.../medina.../MEDINA_Forum_2012_%20Automatisierung.pdf)

can any one suggest me how to proceed and what modules are needed

Comment: I'm willing to bet 90% of this code is completely irrelevant to your question. And I'm not willing to read all of it just to find out that I was right. Please see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help on asking better questions.

Comment: sorry @abarnert i removed the code, i just need to know how to communicate between python and tcl/tk app which can recieve commands through pipes

Comment: Usually you have at least two options: tcp/udp sockets or web services

Comment: @matcheek: No, apps that can receive commands through pipes do not need sockets or web services.

Comment: @abarnert: have not heard about an app that does not have std io pipes :) All of them have. My point is different for anything bigger than a batch of scripts without front interface using pipes over sockets (or web services) it's definitely not a recommended practice. This kind of communication has been common a few decades ago, now you have a lot other options that make debugging and maintaining painless.

Comment: @matcheek. I don't understand what you're saying. The OP has a program that's apparently explicitly designed to be driven over stdin. So the way to drive it is over stdin. Using sockets is not going to help, unless he wants to rewrite the app he's trying to drive (which I doubt he does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the Medina process from your Python program using [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor);

```
 import subprocess

 args = ['medina'] # Add other string arguments if necessary
 medina = subprocess.Popen(args,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The `medina` object now has the attributes `medina.stdin`, `medina.stdout` and `medina.stderr` which are file objects. You can read from stdout and stderr, and write to stdin to communicate with the medina process.

Note that while the documentation recommends that you use the `communicate()` method, this can only be used *once*, because it waits for the sub-process to exit.

But you might want to use [`select.select`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) to regularly check if the aforementioned files stdin and stdout have material for reading available so the buffers don't fill up.

Comment: i understood your method. in the gui what i'm doing is to automate a process i.e i have to check the model imported in the medina gui weather it has met the quality standards or not, to do this i have type the commands in the medina gui command line one by one. so now my question is can i pass the commands through the pipe to medina gui and automatically make it to process the command

Comment: @ayaan You would have to consult the documentation for medina to see if this is possible.

Comment: Note that select can't be used on pipes on Windows, and can only be used on pipes you explicitly fcntl to nonblocking on some Unix platforms, and will always return true for readable (whether blocking or not) on some unix platforms. It's worth searching for async subprocess wrappers on PyPI if you need to do anything fancy. Or, sometimes, using pexpect or similar.

Comment: i think the process you wrote above works thank you @Roland Smith

Comment: Sounds a bit like you want pexpect (http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), it is made for the usecase here.